# Sharing Internet access with neighbor - What do I need?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, wireless-router

My neighbor has an Internet access and a modem/router provided by the ISP. His WiFi signal is strong even in my house, so we want to share the connection.

I need to connect to his signal and create a new WiFi network for my house. However, I'd like the networks to be independent from each other.

Here's a schematic:

[image]

I don't want a cabled connection to his router, since we live in independent homes. What kind of equipment do I need to achieve this? What configurations must be done on this router? I have a 1st gen Raspberry Pi that I can use, if it helps.

Comment: What does it mean for the networks to be independent from each other if you are using the same connection? What does it mean to see a device?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your neighbour should enable a guest network on his side, this will give you internet access but block you network from seeing his and vice versa.

Then, what you want is two antenna system in your house. You can either use a dual band router where you receive at 2.4GHz and transmit out your own SSID at 5Ghz, but if you have any devices that do not support 5Ghz they'll be completely offline. The other route is to get a 2.4Ghz bridge (Ubiquiti nanostation or similar) and then have your route transmit whatever you like.

Please note that doing this is very likely a breach of his contract, so if he gets a nice big fine I take no responsibility.

Comment: Can that "guest network" be created without connecting a cable to his existing router? ie, can I create it from my home?

Comment: Assuming you can log into his modem, yes. But the fact that you couldn't makes me suspicious as to whether this is sanctioned or not.

Comment: I don't have his password yet, but since we get along fine I'm going to ask him to share the connection and split the bill. But I doubt he wants me to connect anything in his home.

Comment: So, I would have physical access to his modem so I could make any config needed, but I won't be able to permanently connect anything via cable. What hw do I need to create a separate ntw in my home?

Comment: His router needs to support guests. If not it would need to be swapped. On your side a regular router (preferably dualband and .11AC) and a WLAN bridge. Assign yourself a different subnet than his just for clarity.